# Having trouble identifying popover text

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm having trouble coming up with a cssSelector statement for the following control.

```
<div class="popover-content">
 <i class="icon-time"></i>
 <h3>24 Hours Risk Free!</h3>
 <p>
   Book now and
   <strong>cancel for free up to 24 hours</strong>
 </p>
</div>
```

I need to simply write a test that verifies this warning exists. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery

```
<a id="btnT" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning">Test</a>

var x = false;
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#btnT').popover({
            placement: 'bottom', 
            title: '${trainingDetail.title}',
            content: '${trainingDetail.description}',
            trigger: 'click',
            html : true,
            container: 'body'
        }).hover(function() {
              if (x) {
                  $(this).popover('hide');
                  x = false;
              }
              else {
                $(this).popover('show');
                x = true;
              }
            }); 
    });
```

Comment: Couldn't I just use something like this?

Comment: css="div[class='popover-content'] > div"

Answer (score 0):

Just find out the div tag using class and get its text. It will get you all the text in it for the h3 and p tags.

```
driver.findElement(By.className("popover-content")).getText();
```

Assuming you are able to already hover over it etc etc... Use the Actions class and moveToElement method.